# add captcha into magento custom form

Tags: magento

I am trying to add a display form in my custom order form , But I can not.
I am calling captcha in this way `$this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info')` but it's not displaying. Here is my URL, just click on Custom order link, you can see a popup, and I want captcha below the form.

http://myechoproject.com/shoponline/index.php/anarkali.html

Here are the my updated files

1.
`App/code/local/Tapati/DesignOrder/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<Tapati_DesignOrder>
  <version>0.1.0</version>
</Tapati_DesignOrder>
</modules>
<global>
<models>
<captcha>
<rewrite>
  <zend>Tapati_DesignOrder_Model_Zend</zend>
</rewrite>
</captcha>
</models>
</global>
<default>
<captcha  translate="label">
<frontend>
<areas>
<contact_us>
  <label>Custom Order Form</label>
</contact_us>
</areas>
</frontend>
</captcha>
<customer>
<captcha>
<always_for>
  <contact_us>1</contact_us>
</always_for>
</captcha>
</customer>
</default>
<frontend>
<routers>
<designorder>
  <use>standard</use>
 <args>
  <module>Tapati_DesignOrder</module>
  <frontName>designorder</frontName>
 </args>
</designorder>
</routers>
</frontend>
<template>
<email>
 <designorder_email_template translate="label" module="designorder">
  <label>Custom Form</label>
  <file>custom_form.html</file>
  <type>text</type>
 </designorder_email_template>
</email>
</template>
<global>
<helpers>
<designorder>
  <class>Tapati_DesignOrder_Helper</class>
</designorder>
</helpers>
</global>
</config>
```

2.
`App/frontend/default/mytheme/default/template/designOrder.xml`

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="captcha/captcha" name="captcha">
 <reference name="head">
  <action method="addJs"><file>mage/captcha.js</file></action>
 </reference>
  <action method="setFormId"><formId>contact_us</formId></action>
  <action method="setImgWidth"><width>230</width></action>
  <action method="setImgHeight"><width>50</width></action>
</block>
</reference>
<designOrder_index_index>
<reference name="root">   
 <action method="setTemplate">
  <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
 </action>   
</reference>   
<reference name="content">   
<block type="designOrder/index" name="designOrder_index" template="designOrder/index.phtml"/>   
</reference>   
</designOrder_index_index>
```

3.
`frontend/mytheme/default/template/designOrder/index.html`

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info');?>
```

Can anyone please point me where I am doing wrong?

Thanks
Tapati

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can use this extension for the concept and then you can make necessary changes. This extension is free.

[Magecomp Recaptcha](https://www.magecomp.com/magento-new-recaptcha.html)